# What's wrong with my prints?

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

I just got my printer for Christmas. It's an Ender 3 Pro. I ran two test prints and they came out great.  However, after changing the filament from the one that came with the printer, my prints started looking like these (the black ones).
I've tried 2-3 different filaments.  I've adjusted my settings temp and speed, I've even cleaned it. All of these are the same slicer settings. The completed white one was from the filament that came with the machine. (Yes, I know they are all phallic-shaped it was an inside joke that was being worked on for gifts).
Any settings or ideas of what can be happening.

[image]
[image]

Comment: different filament or even different colors need different parameters, sometimes dramatically different than what you're used to. Something is WAY off and I really don't think those are the same slicer settings.

Comment: Do you have any of the original filament left? It might be useful to do a test print with that, to see if anything has changed with your printer, or if it's just caused by the filament. If it's the printer, you need to go through appropriate diagnostic steps. If it's the filament, the correct bed/extruder temperatures are usually printed on the side of the reel.

Comment: This looks like volumetric flow is enabled through the printer LCD controller. The top image is a very typical example for a large underextrusion, e.g. what you get when the printer expects volumetric filament flow while it is sliced for filament distance.

Comment: Apart from the points above about testing of your printer with the original filament and  underextrusion, why don't you use simple 1cm cube for testing? Like this one - https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:177694. It would decrease printing time and waste of plastic.